# Specifying element from a class - HTML

Tags: javascript, html, intro.js

I am using intro.js to create a tutorial, and am a bit stuck.
I would like the tutorial to highlight these 3 items highlighted in the image below

[image]

Firstly the red Element, then the Blue element, and then the green tickbox. Looking at the source code (the page is generated on the fly using various JS files) I can see the classes that are being generated to but am having problems with specifying the particular class. The source code for the red area is below (its quite long, so i apologise)

```
<div class="layer-list bound-visible">
   <ul>
      <li class="layer layer-info parent-layer bound-visible">
         <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-visible expanded"></a></div>
         <span class="layer-actions bound-invisible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></span> <span class="widget bound-invisible"></span> <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-mapservice-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-invisible"><a title="" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"></a></span> <span class="display-name">Operational Layers</span> </label> 
      </li>
      <li class="layer">
         <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible"></ul>
         <div class="bound-visible">
            <ul class="layers">
               <li class="layer bound-visible">
                  <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-visible expanded"></a></div>
                  <div class="layer-info layer-enabled">
                     <div class="layer-actions bound-invisible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></div>
                     <div class="widget bound-visible">
                        <div class="widget">
                           <div class="transparency-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><a style="left: 100%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-layer-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-invisible"><a title="" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"></a></span> <span class="display-name">COMPASS2_Conservation</span> </label> 
                  </div>
                  <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible"></ul>
                  <ul class="layers bound-visible">
                     <ul class="layers">
                        <li class="layer bound-visible">
                           <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-invisible collapsed"></a></div>
                           <div class="layer-info layer-enabled">
                              <div class="layer-actions bound-visible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></div>
                              <div class="widget bound-invisible"></div>
                              <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-layer-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-visible"><a title="Protected Trees - Legend" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAABhQTFRF/v//7vXx3evhyeHQstW9mMiodbuNOqxqxn3uOQAAAAh0Uk5TAP/////////VylQyAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAgUlEQVQokY2S2w7AMAhCVxX5/z9e223ZpZLM11PAErft3zSTyCAR2JSIDJGUpJKBRI28i+il3yDMCuVE1SLgOYul2cGy2CNO0VqIX35L2E2+YRZxrRHmTcm+YfYwhCRvdnQEQ/rs5C7ZAIS18bf+zPtKa1sDiQnKuwl1ALN96fiaHTYBBEJVsaCYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a></span> <span class="display-name">Protected Trees</span> </label> 
                           </div>
                           <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible">
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="legend-item leaf clear">
                                    <div class="legend-item children layer-contents">
                                       <div title="Protected Trees" class="legend-swatch"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAABhQTFRF/v//7vXx3evhyeHQstW9mMiodbuNOqxqxn3uOQAAAAh0Uk5TAP/////////VylQyAAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAgUlEQVQokY2S2w7AMAhCVxX5/z9e223ZpZLM11PAErft3zSTyCAR2JSIDJGUpJKBRI28i+il3yDMCuVE1SLgOYul2cGy2CNO0VqIX35L2E2+YRZxrRHmTcm+YfYwhCRvdnQEQ/rs5C7ZAIS18bf+zPtKa1sDiQnKuwl1ALN96fiaHTYBBEJVsaCYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></div>
                                       <span title="Protected Trees" class="legend-item-label">Protected Trees</span> 
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </ul>
                           <ul class="layers bound-invisible"></ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <ul class="layers">
                        <li class="layer bound-visible">
                           <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-invisible collapsed"></a></div>
                           <div class="layer-info layer-enabled">
                              <div class="layer-actions bound-visible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></div>
                              <div class="widget bound-invisible"></div>
                              <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-layer-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-visible"><a title="Click to see legend information for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"><img src="Resources/Images/Icons/legend-16.png"></a></span> <span class="display-name">Listed Buildings</span> </label> 
                           </div>
                           <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible">
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="legend-item leaf clear">
                                    <div class="legend-item children layer-contents">
                                       <div title="I" class="legend-swatch"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAZQTFRF/v//p5nAeU643QAAAAJ0Uk5TAP9bkSK1AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAFElEQVQokWNgoAFgxAJGpUalqA4AJ0wBkeEX5OEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></div>
                                       <span title="I" class="legend-item-label">I</span> 
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="legend-item leaf clear">
                                    <div class="legend-item children layer-contents">
                                       <div title="II" class="legend-swatch"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAZQTFRF/v//v92Uk2hV+QAAAAJ0Uk5TAP9bkSK1AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAFElEQVQokWNgoAFgxAJGpUalqA4AJ0wBkeEX5OEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></div>
                                       <span title="II" class="legend-item-label">II</span> 
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="legend-item leaf clear">
                                    <div class="legend-item children layer-contents">
                                       <div title="II*" class="legend-swatch"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAZQTFRF/v//lMD/gnwoNAAAAAJ0Uk5TAP9bkSK1AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAFElEQVQokWNgoAFgxAJGpUalqA4AJ0wBkeEX5OEAAAAASUVORK5CYII="></div>
                                       <span title="II*" class="legend-item-label">II*</span> 
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </ul>
                           <ul class="layers bound-invisible"></ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <ul class="layers">
                        <li class="layer bound-visible">
                           <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-invisible collapsed"></a></div>
                           <div class="layer-info layer-enabled">
                              <div class="layer-actions bound-visible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></div>
                              <div class="widget bound-invisible"></div>
                              <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-layer-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-visible"><a title="Scheduled Ancient Monuments - Legend" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAxQTFRF/v//6cKohnBg4qt/lElJmQAAAAR0Uk5TAP///7MtQIgAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAArSURBVCiRY2DAAxhxAJAUE1YAkWLGAoiRQrdnVGpwS5ETy7iTDQ6AL4ECABbVA7Xx4JQyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></a></span> <span class="display-name">Scheduled Ancient Monuments</span> </label> 
                           </div>
                           <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible">
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="legend-item leaf clear">
                                    <div class="legend-item children layer-contents">
                                       <div title="Scheduled Ancient Monuments" class="legend-swatch"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAxQTFRF/v//6cKohnBg4qt/lElJmQAAAAR0Uk5TAP///7MtQIgAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAArSURBVCiRY2DAAxhxAJAUE1YAkWLGAoiRQrdnVGpwS5ETy7iTDQ6AL4ECABbVA7Xx4JQyAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"></div>
                                       <span title="Scheduled Ancient Monuments" class="legend-item-label">Scheduled Ancient Monuments</span> 
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </ul>
                           <ul class="layers bound-invisible"></ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                     <ul class="layers">
                        <li class="layer bound-visible">
                           <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-invisible collapsed"></a></div>
                           <div class="layer-info layer-enabled">
                              <div class="layer-actions bound-visible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></div>
                              <div class="widget bound-invisible"></div>
                              <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-layer-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-visible"><a title="Conservation Areas - Legend" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAZQTFRF/v//dE0AiLHxHwAAAAJ0Uk5TAP9bkSK1AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAT0lEQVQokbXRwQoAIAgDUP3/n66TztkCgzwU+AiZmV3KRf2ifebs6MWFVqkYERoTWaG0TmGYiwxfkZ0je59VTEXu20DTkfs2xpGffnlOshbfOwFc9elasgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></a></span> <span class="display-name">Conservation Areas</span> </label> 
                           </div>
                           <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible">
                              <ul>
                                 <li class="legend-item leaf clear">
                                    <div class="legend-item children layer-contents">
                                       <div title="Conservation Areas" class="legend-swatch"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABoAAAAaCAMAAACelLz8AAAAAXNSR0IB2cksfwAAAAZQTFRF/v//dE0AiLHxHwAAAAJ0Uk5TAP9bkSK1AAAACXBIWXMAAA7EAAAOxAGVKw4bAAAAT0lEQVQokbXRwQoAIAgDUP3/n66TztkCgzwU+AiZmV3KRf2ifebs6MWFVqkYERoTWaG0TmGYiwxfkZ0je59VTEXu20DTkfs2xpGffnlOshbfOwFc9elasgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="></div>
                                       <span title="Conservation Areas" class="legend-item-label">Conservation Areas</span> 
                                    </div>
                                 </li>
                              </ul>
                           </ul>
                           <ul class="layers bound-invisible"></ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <ul>
      <li class="layer layer-info parent-layer bound-visible">
         <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-visible expanded"></a></div>
         <span class="layer-actions bound-invisible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></span> <span class="widget bound-invisible"></span> <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-mapservice-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-invisible"><a title="" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"></a></span> <span class="display-name">BaseMaps</span> </label> 
      </li>
      <li class="layer">
         <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible"></ul>
         <div class="bound-visible">
            <ul class="layers">
               <li class="layer bound-visible">
                  <div class="layer-item-expander"><a href="javascript: void(0)" class="tree-expander bound-invisible expanded"></a></div>
                  <div class="layer-info layer-enabled">
                     <div class="layer-actions bound-invisible"><a title="Click to see layer actions available for this layer" href="javascript: void(0)" class="chevron-right-16"></a></div>
                     <div class="widget bound-visible">
                        <div class="widget">
                           <div class="transparency-slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><a style="left: 100%;" class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#"></a></div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                     <label class="layer-contents"> <span class="layer-item-ctrl"><input type="checkbox"></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl layer-list-layer-icon bound-invisible"><img src="" title=""></span> <span class="layer-item-ctrl bound-invisible"><a title="" href="javascript: void(0)" class="layer-list-legend-icon"></a></span> <span class="display-name">baseMapCached</span> </label> 
                  </div>
                  <ul class="legend-list bound-invisible"></ul>
                  <ul class="layers bound-visible"></ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This is the code intro.js code I am using, which does not get picked up.

```
      { 
        element: '.layer-item-ctrl',
        intro: "This is the checkbox to turn layers on and off - CLASS"
      }
```

I used the tutorial from http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/introjs-step-by-step-guide-tutorial/ to get started.

So my question is how do I specify the the correct blue area, if there are multiple `<label class="layer-contents">` within the code and how do i specify the correct tickbox, if there multiple `type="checkbox"` within the code.

Comment: What is the question? You're having trouble 'specifying the class' -- what do you mean? Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it working using the following

```
document.querySelectorAll('[class="toolbar-item toolbar-group bound-visible"]')[0]
```